# @nuxt/auth using query parameters for reddirect login

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I have specified in the plugin (@nuxt/auth v.5.0.0) settings the following settings for redirection:
redirect: `{ login: '/?auth=login', logout: '/', callback: '/?auth=login', home: false }`,

And with a direct transition (it is with a direct transition) to a protected route, I get an error: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

When setting `login: '/auth'`, there is no such problem, the error is when passing query parameters. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: It could potentially be a redirect loop as you have login and callback using the same redirect target, but it depends on the code you have to handle `/?auth=login`, in particular whether or not it is checking whether the user is logged in yet or not. Could you share that code?